# sparkr dataframe filter by column using regex

Tags: r, sparkr

I have a `sparkR` dataframe called Tweets with a column named `bodyText`.

What I am trying to do is filter the dataframe by a regex condition on the bodyText. So for example filter by tweets that have "rally" or "protest" in the bodyText.

What I have tried so far is:

```
subset(twitter_df, grepl("(?<=\\b)rally", twitter_df$bodyText, ignore.case = TRUE))
filter(twitter_df, grepl("(?<=\\b)rally", twitter_df$bodyText, ignore.case = TRUE))
```

but in both cases receive this error:

> Error in as.character.default(x) :
>     no method for coercing this S4 class to a vector
>   Calls: main ... .local -> [ -> grepl -> as.character -> as.character.default

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert the Spark data frame to a rdd, apply the filter and convert it back:

```
# setup reproducable sample
df <- data.frame(id=c(1:4), bodyText=c("rally","protest","text1","text2"))
head(twitter_df.filtered)
twitter_df <- as.DataFrame(df)
head(twitter_df)


# convert to rdd
twitter_df.rdd <- SparkR:::toRDD(twitter_df)
# filter rdd
twitter_df.rdd.filtered <- SparkR:::filterRDD(twitter_df.rdd, function(s) { grepl("(?<=\\b)rally", s$bodyText, ignore.case = TRUE, perl = TRUE) })
# convert to Spark data frame
twitter_df.filtered <- as.DataFrame(twitter_df.rdd.filtered)
head(twitter_df.filtered)
```

Note the parameter `perl` is set to `TRUE` or the used expression is invalid.

Comment: Works, thanks very much. I just had to add sqlContext to as.DataFrame: 
`as.DataFrame(sqlContext, df)`

Answer (score 0):

If you use the [Spark Sql in SparkR](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sparkr.html#running-sql-queries-from-sparkr), it could be as simple as:

```
df <- data.frame(id=c(1:4), bodyText=c("rally","protest","text1","text2"))

createOrReplaceTempView(df, "tweets")
rallys <- head(sql("SELECT * FROM tweets WHERE bodyText rlike 'rally'"))

print(rallys)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it will be by using `SparkR:::rlike`
for a `sparkdataframe`:

```
df_filtered <- SparkR:::filter(df,SparkR:::rlike(df$bodyText,"(?<=\\b)rally"))
```

The syntax is:

```
df_filtered <- SparkR:::filter(Dataframe,SparkR:::rlike(column_name,regex))
```

This is better than converting spark data frame to an rdd and then converting it back again to a data frame.